# ColdFusion generated 403 response does not trigger IIS6 403 error page

Tags: coldfusion, iis-6, custom-error-pages

I am using the following line of code in several places in a ColdFusion website application, which will cause the page to respond with a 403 error code, but, IIS6 does not show the 403 error as specified in "Custom Errors". This happens whether I use the default settings, the built-in IIS error pages, or my own custom URL or File setting:

**Application.cfc:**

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returntype="Boolean">
    <cfargument name="targetPage" type="String" required="true" />

    <cfif notAuthorized>    
        <cfheader statusCode="403" statusText="Forbidden" />

        <cfreturn false />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

This code properly triggers the 403 error in IIS7/7.5, but not in IIS6.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you share your web.config from website root?

Comment: Possibly a better question for ServerFault?

Comment: @AnitKumar there is no web.config file at the root of the IIS6 website.

Comment: @AdamCameron I posted this here because the result I'm getting is because of a programming change not a server setting.

Comment: Sure, but it'll be an IIS config issue: it's not set to heed HTTP error statuses coming back from CF. I do not know how to fix it, but that should give you something to go on, or to ask about on Server Fault.

Comment: @AdamCameron Yeah, I understand where you are coming from, but I figured (hoped) another developer/programmer might have run into this in the past.